# Prove that $\frac{x}{(1+x)\log(1+x)}$ is monotonically decreasing for $x\geq 0$

Tags: calculus, real-analysis

Prove that $\frac{x}{(1+x)\log(1+x)}$ is monotonically decreasing for $x\geq 0$.

I'm having a lot of trouble with this, partly because of the singularity in $\frac{1}{\log(1+x)}$ at $x=0$. Plotting it it's clear that it's monotonically decreasing, and that it's $\leq 1$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Hint:
let
$$f(x)=\dfrac{x}{(1+x)\ln{(1+x)}}\Longrightarrow f'(x)=\dfrac{\ln{(1+x)}-x}{(x+1)^2\ln^2{(x+1)}}\le 0$$
and it is well known $$\ln{(1+x)}<x$$

Answer (score 1):

We show the reciprocal $\log(1+x)\left(1+\frac{1}{x}\right)$ is increasing. The derivative is $-\frac{\log(1+x)}{x^2}+\frac{1}{x}$, which is $\frac{1}{x^2}(x-\log(1+x))$. It is standard that this is positive for $x\gt 0$.